# How to specify the location of the label box for python pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have searched around for a while but cannot find a good answer.

How to specify the location of the label box on a plot so that it does not obstruct the lines?

Ex: The label box in this plot I made blocked the lines

[image]

```
def savePlt(tCoords, yCoords, perturbedYCoords1, perturbedYCoords2):
plt.plot(tCoords, yCoords, 'co', label="(t, y*)")
plt.plot(tCoords, perturbedYCoords1, 'yo', label="(t, y1)")
plt.plot(tCoords, perturbedYCoords2, 'ko', label="(t, y2)")
plt.legend()    

plt.hold(False)
plt.savefig("cheezberger")
return
```

Comment: You should include a simplified version of the code you used to generate this image.  It is hard to help you if we have to guess what your code is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making the assumption that you are using legend... When you call it use the loc keyword.  E.g.

```
legend(loc=1)
```

loc=1 places the legend in the upper right. Here are the position/number pairings:

upper right: 1; 
upper left: 2;
lower left: 3;
lower right: 4;
right: 5;
center left: 6;
center right: 7;
lower center: 8;
upper center: 9;
center: 10;

Link: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Comment: Please include link to the documentation (http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend)